# How I got this answer

Tags: arithmetic, puzzle

Well i am new to this forum but old to stack exchange but i don't know much about mathmatics tags so sorry for the wrong tags if any.
I have a question, but i want to know how i got its answer as 'D'

> Aslam has $4$ times as many books as Salman and $5$ times as many as Javed. If Javed has more than $40$ books, what is the least number of books that Aslam could have?

(A) $200$

(B) $205$

(C) $210$

(D) $220$

(E) $24$

Answer: $(D)$

Well I don't know how the answer is '$220$'. I am new to this field as well but according to me its answer should be $200$. Any ideas?

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Javes has **more than** $40$ books, he has **at least** $41$ books. Thus, Aslam has at least $5\cdot 41=205$ books. Since his number of books is a multiple of $4$ and $5$, it is a multiple of $20$. Thus, he has at least $220$ books.

Say that $a$ is the number of books Aslam has. We know that $4|a$ ($4$ divides $a$) and that $5|a$. In general, if $k|x$ and $l|x$, it follows that $\text{lcm}(k,l)|x$, where $\text{lcm}(k,l)$ is the [least common multiple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of $k$ and $l$. Since the smallest number that is a multiple of both $4$ and $5$ is $20$, it follows that $20|a$.

Comment: Can you please give better explanation of this line , `Since his number of books is a multiple of 4 and 5, it is a multiple of 20`

Comment: If it helps, you can turn the notation around. If $X=4a$ and $X=5b$, then $4a=5b$ which means $a=5b/4$. But $a$ must be an integer so the top of the fraction has to be divisible by 4. This cannot happen unless $b$ is a multiple of 4, that is, $b=4c$. But then $X=5(4c)=20c$, so $X$ is a multiple of 20.